# How to Handle Blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> my controller function is. I passed data through bidder array but array data can't print

```
public function bidders()
{
    $payments = \App\Models\Payment::all();
    $posts = Post::all()->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $postid = $post->id;
        $bidder[] = Bid::all()->where('post_id','=',$postid);
    }

    return view('user.student.student-post-bidders',compact('bidder','posts','payments'));
}
```

> Here is my blade in this blade my data print from DB.
>   How can I print array? indexes of array print in a blade

```
@php
    dd($bidder);
    $index = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($bidder as $bid)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        @if($post->id == $bid[$index]['post_id'])
            <div class="row" >
                <!-- Dashboard Box -->
                <div class="col-xl-12" >
                    <div class="dashboard-box margin-top-0">
                        <!-- Headline -->
                            <div class="headline">
                                <h4><strong><span class="bg-danger text-center" style="margin-left: 46px">Your Post Title:</span>{{$bid[$index]->Post->title}}</strong></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <ul class="dashboard-box-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <!-- Overview -->
                                        <div class="freelancer-overview manage-candidates">
                                            <div class="freelancer-overview-inner">

                                                <!-- Avatar -->

                                                <div class="freelancer-avatar">
                                                    <div class="verified-badge"></div>

                                                    @if($bid[$index]->Tutor->profile_Image=='')

                                                        <img data-cfsrc="{{asset('asset/images/user-avatar-placeholder.png')}}" alt="" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">

                                                    @else
{{--                                                            {{asset('storage/app/public/profileImages/' . $pic->profile_Image)}}--}}

                                                        <a href=""><img data-cfsrc="{{asset('storage/app/public/profileImages/' . $bid[$index]->Tutor->profile_Image)}}" alt="" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;"></a>
                                                    @endif
                                                </div>


                                                <!-- Name -->
                                                <div class="freelancer-name">

                                                    <h4><a href="">{{$bid[$index]->Tutor->name}}</a></h4>

                                                    <!-- Details -->
                                                    <strong><span>Subject:</span></strong>

                                                    @foreach($bid[$index]->Tutor->subject as $sub)

                                                        <strong><span>{{\App\Models\Subject::find($sub->pivot->subject_id)->subject}}</span></strong>

                                                    @endforeach
                                                    <!-- Rating -->
                                                    <div class="freelancer-rating">
                                                        <div class="star-rating" data-rating="{{$bid[$index]->Tutor->rating}}"></div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <!-- Bid Details -->

                                                    <ul class="dashboard-task-info bid-info">
                                                        <li><strong id="{{ $bid[$index]->id}}">PKR:{{$bid[$index]->bid_price}}</strong><span>Fixed Price</span></li>
                                                        <li><strong>Days:{{$bid[$index]->days}}</strong><span>Delivery Time</span></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <!-- Buttons -->
                                                    <div class="buttons-to-right always-visible margin-top-25 margin-bottom-0" onclick=" indexID({{$i}})">
                                                        <a href="#small-dialog-1"
                                                               onclick="moveprice({{ $bid[$index]->id}}), payment({{ $bid[$index]->id}})" class="popup-with-zoom-anim button ripple-effect"
                                                               @foreach($payments as $pay)  @if($bid[$index]->post_id == $pay->post_id) id="hide" @endif @endforeach><i class="icon-material-outline-check "></i> Accept Bid</a>
{{--                                                       @dd($bid->id)--}}
                                                        <a href="{{url('student-messages',$bid[$i]->id)}}" class=" button dark ripple-effect"><i class="icon-feather-mail"></i> Send Message</a>
                                                        <a  id="btn" class="button gray ripple-effect ico" onclick="removeBid({{$bid[$index]->id}})" title="Remove Bid" data-tippy-placement="top"><i class="icon-feather-trash-2"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <span style="visibility: hidden">{{$i++}}</span>
            @endif

        @endforeach
        @php
            $index++;
        @endphp

    @endforeach
```

> When I run code error will be occur 
>   offset 1 I need all data print in a blade
>   How to print array index wise

[image]

Comment: Try a ```{{dd($bid)}}``` inside 1st foreach.

Comment: why don't you try to use relationships of eloquents?

Answer (score 1):

you should use relations,
if you want to show the list of bidders then in bidders model

> app/bidders.php

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Assuming that you have proper standards in table structure for mapping eloquent.

then you need to change your bidders function as below

```
public function bidders()
{
    $payments = \App\Models\Payment::get();
    $bidders = Bidder::whereHas('post', function($post) {
        return $post->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id);
        //Provides a filter for bidders, post which are related to user
    })->with('post')->get();

    return view('user.student.student-post-bidders',compact('bidders', 'payments'));
}
```

And there should be only one loop for bidders on blade as below.

`Here is your answer why array is not appearing in blade check in comments for json_encode`

```
@foreach($bidders as $bid)
    {{$bid->id}} //gives you bid parameters
    {{json_encode($bid->post)}} //this will get all the post details array/object is not printable on blade so encoded to json just for display purpose

    //suppose you need only name from post then
    {{$bid->post->name}};
@endforeach
```

This will lower your code length, as well as improve performance due to eager loading and less looping. Also removes stuff like creating array and maintain index and if condition on blade for id check.

That's it.
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to refactoring your code ),
first of all use $bid->{$index} instead of this $bid[$index]. you have collection but you can use it as array 
do you want to group your bidder by post_id ?